# How to regex search this string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that is the output of the package causalimpact, and I need to get the numbers of the actual average and cumulative effects that are somewhere in this string:

"Posterior Inference {Causal Impact}\n                          Average            Cumulative\nActual                    3.43               13.7\nPrediction (s.d.)         3.38 (0.02)        13.53 (0.08)\n95% CI                    [3.34, 3.42]       [13.38, 13.68]\n\nAbsolute effect (s.d.)    0.04 (0.02)        0.17 (0.08)\n95% CI                    [0.01, 0.08]       [0.02, 0.33]\n\nRelative effect (s.d.)    1.27% (0.57%)      1.27% (0.57%)\n95% CI                    [0.18%, 2.41%]     [0.18%, 2.41%]\n\nPosterior tail-area probability p: 0.01\nPosterior prob. of a causal effect: 99.2%\n\nFor more details run the command: print(impact.summary('report'))"

when I do print(ci.summary) I get a nice and organized table like this:

```
Posterior Inference {Causal Impact}
                          Average            Cumulative
Actual                    3.43               13.7
Prediction (s.d.)         3.38 (0.02)        13.53 (0.08)
95% CI                    [3.34, 3.42]       [13.38, 13.68]

Absolute effect (s.d.)    0.04 (0.02)        0.17 (0.08)
95% CI                    [0.01, 0.08]       [0.02, 0.33]

Relative effect (s.d.)    1.27% (0.57%)      1.27% (0.57%)
95% CI                    [0.18%, 2.41%]     [0.18%, 2.41%]

Posterior tail-area probability p: 0.01
Posterior prob. of a causal effect: 99.2%

For more details run the command: print(impact.summary('report'))
```

how can I do a re.search and get the actual, absolute and relative effects?

this is what I am currently using for the p-value:

```
r1 = re.search('tail-area probability p: (.+?)\nPosterior prob.', ci.summary())
```

Comment: I think you can achieve this with String search `startswith` with each line

Answer (score 1):

You could use `r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?'` to find the numbers in your text together with [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) and regex named groups.

```py
import re

s = '''
Posterior Inference {Causal Impact}\n Average Cumulative\nActual 3.43 13.7\nPrediction (s.d.) 3.38 (0.02) 13.53 (0.08)\n95% CI [3.34, 3.42] [13.38, 13.68]\n\nAbsolute effect (s.d.) 0.04 (0.02) 0.17 (0.08)\n95% CI [0.01, 0.08] [0.02, 0.33]\n\nRelative effect (s.d.) 1.27% (0.57%) 1.27% (0.57%)\n95% CI [0.18%, 2.41%] [0.18%, 2.41%]\n\nPosterior tail-area probability p: 0.01\nPosterior prob. of a causal effect: 99.2%\n\nFor more details run the command: print(impact.summary('report'))
'''

# get digits optionally follow by a decimal part and prefixed with a negative sign.
nums = r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?'

regex = re.compile(
    rf"Actual\s(?P<actual_avg>{nums}).*?"
    rf"(?P<actual_cumul>{nums})\n.*?"
    rf"Absolute effect \(s\.d\.\)\s(?P<abs_avg>{nums}).*?"
    rf"\(.*?\).*?(?P<abs_cumul>{nums}).*?"
    rf"Relative effect \(s\.d\.\)\s(?P<relative_avg>{nums})%.*?"
    rf"\(.*?\).*?(?P<relative_cumul>{nums})%.*?"
, re.DOTALL)

for r in regex.finditer(s):
    print(r.groupdict())
```

```py
{
    "actual_avg": "3.43",
    "actual_cumul": "13.7",
    "abs_avg": "0.04",
    "abs_cumul": "0.17",
    "relative_avg": "1.27",
    "relative_cumul": "1.27",
}
```